# How to invoke default VertexShapeFunction and EdgeShapeFunction from custom ones?

Tags: graphs-and-networks

For this question, `g` is a `Graph` object (of order ~2K) such that the `VertexWeight` and `EdgeWeight` properties are defined for every vertex and edge, respectively, and have values in the unit interval<sup>1</sup>.

I want to implement custom functions to set `g`'s `VertexShapeFunction` and `EdgeShapeFunction` properties to.  I want these functions to have this form:

```
(* for VertexShapeFunction *)
If[PropertyValue[{g, #2}, VertexWeight] < cutoff,
   invisibleVertex,
   defaultVertex[##]] &

(* for EdgeShapeFunction *)
If[PropertyValue[{g, #2}, EdgeWeight] < cutoff,
   invisibleEdge,
   defaultEdge[##]] &
```

(The symbol `cutoff` represents an external parameter that I intend to modify repeatedly to affect how the graph is displayed.  The intent is that as one lowers the value of `cutoff`, more vertices and edges will become visible.  The *positions* of vertices and edges should never change as one varies `cutoff`.)

By dumb (and lengthy) trial-and-error, I've found that setting

```
invisibleVertex = Directive[Opacity[0], EdgeForm[None]];
invisibleEdge = {};
```

produces adequate results (although these settings are literally clueless, and I welcome more informed alternatives).

I have not found anything remotely adequate to put in the locations indicated by the placeholders `defaultVertex[##]` and `defaultEdge[##]` above.

Is there a way to do what I'm trying to do?

---

<sup><sup>Also, FWIW, for each vertex, the value of its `VertexWeight` property is the maximum of the `EdgeWeight` property of all the edges incident upon it, or -1 if there are no such edges.</sup></sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HighlightGraph` combined with `Style` may be a good alternative:

```
g1 = CompleteGraph[10, EdgeWeight -> eweights, 
   VertexWeight -> vweights, ImageSize -> 300,
   VertexShapeFunction -> "Star", VertexSize -> .3, 
   VertexStyle -> Orange, EdgeShapeFunction -> "FilledArcArrow", 
   EdgeStyle -> Directive[{Blue, Thick}]];
```

[image]

```
vweights = RandomReal[1, {VertexCount[g1]}];
eweights = RandomReal[1, {EdgeCount[g1]}];
cutoff = .5;
sv = Select[VertexList[g1], PropertyValue[{g1, #}, VertexWeight] < cutoff &];
se = Select[EdgeList[g1], PropertyValue[{g1, #}, EdgeWeight] < cutoff &];

g2 = HighlightGraph[g1, Style[#, Opacity[0.], Thickness[0.], EdgeForm[]] & /@  Join[sv, se]];

Row[{g1, g2}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]